# checked radiobutton doesn't work after PHP gets the MySQL request

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, modal-dialog, radio-button

i'm having trouble with a form that needs to be filled out from a MySql request. It all works find until the radiobuttons.Here is my code:

```
$get_entry = 'SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE id="'.$given_id.'"';

$sql_get_query = mysql_query($get_entry); 

while($row_sql_get_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get_query)){                                  
$get_entry_gender = $row_sql_get_query['gender'];   
$get_entry_type = $row_sql_get_query['type'];                            
}

echo '
input type="radio" name="sex" value="0"'; if ($get_entry_gender == 0)
{echo 'checked';} echo '>Male</input> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="0"'; if ($get_entry_type == 0)
{echo 'checked';}echo '>Home</input></br> 
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"'; if ($get_entry_gender == 1)
{echo 'checked';} echo '>Female</input> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="1"'; if ($get_entry_type == 1)
{echo 'checked';} echo '>Yard</input></br>';
```

The whole code is in a while-loop since im creating multiple modals with different content, but i don't see how that might be the problem. The code works for getting different variables with different form type like

```
<input type="text"> 
<input type="select">
<input type="textfield">
```

If i remove the "name" from the radiobuttons code, the php code works,but than you can select 2 values for the same type of information.

Comment: I don't see any concatenation in your inputs, and your `if` statements are kinda weird, are those valid syntax?

Comment: That syntax is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: The syntax looks wrong because im copying just fractions of the whole code. The inputs are in a echo statement.